# falling back on batch processing and stuck

Tags: batch-file, text

So I have this file, I am using a program to extract the table data from the page links in it.
I need to convert from:

> s://###.genericcardguide.com/spoiler/*page name*.html

To

> table2csv ####s://###.genericcardguide.com/spoiler/*page name*.html > *page name*.csv

There are multiple links in the text file in question. I have tried everything I know, but it has been a long time since I did batch programming.

Any help would be appreciated. The idea it to create a batch file that will run each line in sequence. So I am trying to use a batch file to create a batch file, and it would be a bonus if the first batch file could run the one it creates at the end.

So I have come up with the following code:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (sets.txt) do (
    SET _result=%%a:~41,-4%
    @echo table2csv.exe ####s://###.genericcardguide.com/spoilers/%_result%.html > %_result%.csv >> setsT.bat
)
:end_for
```

However, it isn't readin the information from the sets.txt file in the same folder.

Comment: Could you show us the coding that you already have? What's the problem with that coding?

Comment: I have just tried a couple examples on here, but they mostly deal with removing text from the string. I haven't been able to alter the test in the way I need it to.

Comment: Ideally I would want it to isolate the parts after spoilers/ and output a line to the new file something like                                  "table2csv http://www.genericcardguide.com/spoiler/ & pagename & " > " & pagename &".csv > sets.bat

Comment: I have been trying to use vb, but would prefer to keep file size down with batch, perhaps I should have stated that in the beginning

Comment: OK, so I figured out most of it with this code:                                                        <code> SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (sets.txt) do (
set var=%%~a
SET result=!var:~41,-5!
echo !result!
@echo table2csv.exe https://www.yugiohcardguide.com/spoilers/!result!.html ">" !result!.csv >> setsT.bat)

:end_for           </code>                but can't figure out how to insert the > without the quotes

Comment: escape it with a caret: `echo ^>`